# ASP.NET Core Authentication (2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a custom(ish) authentication with ASP.NET Core 2.2. I've seen this asked in a few places, however, I haven't seen the outcome I am getting.

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0);
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Signin code:

```
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserId", userId.ToString()));
             //userId is set above
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProperties);
```

The result:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**
**InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Cookies",...)?**

No matter what options I put in the Startup, I get that error.
The odd part is, I've tried using the code right from the Microsoft Docs site (which is similar/exactly the same? as the code I'm currently using), as well as code from another custom application (that works) and every time, I get the same error.

Update:

Not sure if this helps or hinders, but I stumbled upon something else. It seems that if I add other things to startup.cs they will not get configured correctly either. For example, I added Session:

`services.AddSession()`
and
`app.UseSession()`
in their respective methods, and I'm getting an error message consistent with Session not being set up in the middleware pipeline (Error message: `InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.`)

Has anyone ever seen this behavior before??

Comment: That doesn’t really make sense. That error message shouldn’t be there if you call `AddCookie()` as shown in your code. – Where do you call your code from, where is that? And where does `HttpContext` come from?

Comment: @poke I agree 100% it doesn't make sense. The code is being called from the `HomeController`, in the Index method, so pretty much one of the first things (it does some stuff to gather the user information from the db from a weird token-y object that is passed from an outside source). `HttpContext` is coming from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`

Comment: @SlackerCoder I tried your code with ASP.NET Core `2.2.401`, but it works fine for me. Is there a demo that reproduces?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to check authorization (`UseAuthorization`)  **BEFORE** HSTS / http redirect code? The typical templates place it afterwards and before or after the static middleware (depending on if you want to protect the static files with the login too or not). Having the `UseAuthorization` first implies you want the user be authorized, even if he comes from http (and hence use an unsecure connection). Usually you want to redirect the user to http or force the browser to use https (via hsts) in future

Comment: @TSeng Yeah, sorry, this was an attempt to try and come up with a random solution to this issue (nothing I've done so far worked, and as poke and itminus pointed out, this really *should* work). It is meant to be below, I just didn't move it back before I posted this sample. Thanks for pointing it out though, I probably would have forgotten to move it back!

Comment: @itminus I've managed to get it working (in a new project) in `2.2.401` as well, so there's something going on with the current project I'm working on. Going to fight with it some more today.

Answer (score 0):

So here's one for the ages!

I "solved" the issue. 
My program.cs file was seemingly pointing to a DIFFERENT startup.cs file. I removed ALL the nuget packages and re-installed them, but as I was, the startup.cs file changed completely. After further investigation, when clicking on the startup.cs from my web project, it would open the startup.cs from my WebApi project (same solution). So, all the edits I was making were being applied to the WebApi project, NOT the web project.

For some reason, uninstalling and re-installing all the nuget packages "fixed" the link. I wouldn't believe it and just assume it was me being an idiot if (a) I hadn't just experienced this oddity myself and (b) someone was literally standing over my shoulder watching this whole thing unfold (from yesterday, he was my "second pair of eyes"). We were both shocked by what was happening and the "fix" for the issue.

So, the comments from poke and itminus were 100% correct, it *should* have worked, and in fact, it probably would have worked, had it been pointing to the correct startup.cs file. I still don't know what happened (in the background?) to cause the file to be pointing incorrectly, but for now, it seems to be working.

I did get this error in VS2019 (16.2.5):

[image: Visual Studio Error]

So, I wonder if that had something to do with the problem?

Thanks for all the comments everyone, hopefully his can help someone if they ever come across this (which, I really hope no one ever sees this!).